# How to stop Highchart Navigator from going out of the available range on scroll?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stock, navigator

The Highchart Navigator is going out of bounds when I try to change the range.

I tried a lot of available options like :

OverScroll:false
AfterSetExtreme function
setting gridLineWidth according to the PlotWidthX and many more but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.